# How to configure druid batch indexing jobs dynamic EMR cluster for batch ingestion?

Tags: airflow, druid

I am trying to automate druid batch ingestion using Airflow. My data pipeline creates EMR cluster on demand and shut it down once druid indexing is completed. But for druid we need to have Hadoop configurations in druid server folder [ref](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/hadoop.html#elastic-mapreduce). This is blocking me from dynamic EMR clusters. Can we override Hadoop connection details in Job configuration or is there a way to support multiple indexing jobs to use different EMR clusters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried out overriding the parameters ( Hadoop configuration) in `core-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,mapred-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml` as [Job properties](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/hadoop.html#jobproperties) in druid indexing job. It worked. In that case no need of copying the above files in druid server.

Just used below python program to convert the properties to json key value pairs from xml files. Can do the same for all the files and pass everything as indexing job payload. The below thing can be automated using airflow after creating different EMR clusters.

````
import json
import xmltodict
path = 'mypath'
file = 'yarn-site.xml'
with open(os.path.join(path,file)) as xml_file:
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
    xml_file.close()
    druid_dict = {property.get('name'):property.get('value') for property in data_dict.get('configuration').get('property') }
    print(json.dumps(druid_dict)) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In researching how this might be done, I found `hadoopDependencyCoordinates` property here: https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.22.1/ingestion/hadoop.html#task-syntax

which seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks. But that seems like an option to change hadoop libraries if our EMR hadoop is running [on different hadoop version than in the druid](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/other-hadoop.html#preferred-load-using-druids-standard-mechanism). I am looking for some option to override the hadoop cluster configuration mentioned [here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/cluster.html#configure-for-connecting-to-hadoop-optional) like above. Basically I want an option in my ingestion spec to point to different core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, mapred-site.xml.

Comment: I am thinking if I override the values in core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, mapred-site.xml via [job properties](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/hadoop.html#jobproperties) will that work ?